# PowerShell: Copy-Item within PSSession ignores -Filter -Include -Exclude

Tags: powershell, copy-item

Using the PowerShell command `Copy-Item` to copy files works fine locally, but when running it in a **PSSession**, the options *-Filter*, *-Include* and *-Exclude* show **no effect** while copying files **from the remote host to the local machine**. I am running PowerShell 5.1 both on the local and the remote machine.

Here, the examples:

- Local --> local: **works** fine (i.e. it copies only txt-files)

  ```
  Copy-Item -Path C:\run\* -Filter *.txt -Destination C:\test\
  ```
- Remote --> local: **does not work correctly** (disregards from the filter settings and copies all files)

  ```
  $sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName <ComputerName> -Credential $cred
  Copy-Item -FromSession $sess -Path C:\run\* -Filter *.txt -Destination C:\test\
  ```

  The same holds when using `-Include *.txt` or `-Exclude *.csv`.
- Local --> remote: **works** fine (copiyng only txt-files):

  ```
  $sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName <ComputerName> -Credential $cred
  Copy-Item -ToSession $sess -Path C:\run\* -Filter *.txt -Destination C:\test\
  ```

Thanks for any hints on what I am doing wrong!

Comment: Similar issue at this link with no solution: https://powershell.org/forums/topic/copy-item-from-pssession/

Comment: Not that it answers the question, but one solution would be to use ```Enter-PSSession``` to run the Local --> Remote copy from your current remote. So, get a session on the remote box, then from that session, get a session on your local box, and then run the local -> remote copy from your question.

Comment: I want to avoid `Enter-PSSession` because the script is supposed to be run without user interaction. Should have said that before, sorry.

Comment: Here, our current **workaround** so far (zipping with filter settings, copying, unzipping): first `Invoke-Command -Session $sess -Scriptblock {Get-ChildItem C:\onremote\* -Include *.txt | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "C:\onremote\textfiles.zip" -Force}`, then, `Copy-Item "C:\onremote\textfiles.zip" -Destination "C:\onlocal\" -FromSession $sess -Recurse -Force`, and finally `Expand-Archive -Path "C:\onlocal\textfiles.zip" -DestinationPath "C:\onlocal\" -Force`.

Answer (score 0):

We all have come to know that with PowerShell there are multiple ways to do X or Y. Why not just use Invoke-Command?

```
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName <ComputerName> -Credential $cred

Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {
    Copy-Item -Path 'C:\run\*' -Filter '*.txt' -Destination 'C:\test\'
}
```

Or just directly

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { 
    Copy-Item -Path 'C:\run\*' -Filter '*.txt' -Destination 'C:\test\' 
}
```

Comment: This will copy files from one place on the remote to another place on the remote.applying the filters correctly. However, I would like to copy them from the remote to my local machine with the filters working. So far, we are using a workaround where we first zip the  files we want and then copying the resulting zip file and uncompressing it on the local machine: see my comment above.